# pushState and back button works but content doesn't change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

It does load a new page and the url does update, but when I press the back button, only the url has changed without refreshing but the content doesn't.

```
$('button').click(function(){
  window.history.pushState({}, '', 'page2.php');
  $('body').html('<div class="loading.gif"></div>');

  //Load Page
  $.get('page2.php', function(data){
    $('body').html(data);
  };

  //Edited 
  $(window).bind('popstate', function(){
    //What should I code here??
  });
});
```

Comment: the $.get(...) call is missing a closing parenthesis, but that's probably just an issue in your example.

Is the loading image showing up?

Comment: Yes, the image does show up. My problem is that the back button doesn't retrieve the previous content.

Answer (score 9):

I did something like that :

```
    $(window).bind('popstate', function(){
  window.location.href = window.location.href;
  });
```

And it work wonderful.
The code is taking the location from the url and redirect to this url.

Comment: It is full page reload. It is not what History API intended for.

Answer (score 5):

I use this to change bar adress and save current state, including current html body, and i reload it on back bouton click without any other ajax call. All is saved in your browser :

1. ```
   $(document).ajaxComplete(function(ev, jqXHR, settings) {

       var stateObj = { url: settings.url, innerhtml: document.body.innerHTML };
       window.history.pushState(stateObj, settings.url, settings.url);
   });


   window.onpopstate = function (event) {
       var currentState = history.state;
       document.body.innerHTML = currentState.innerhtml;
   };
   ```

Comment: And what is the browser limits for saving objects in states?

Comment: In firefox: "Because Firefox saves state objects to the user's disk so they can be restored after the user restarts the browser, we impose a size limit of 640k characters on the serialized representation of a state object."

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the popstate event. When you click the back button after pushing a state, the page receives the popstate event. In it you need to replace the page contents with the correct page.

See [an example from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onpopstate#The_popstate_event)

Updated code:

```
$('button').click(function(){
  // Store some information in the state being pushed
  window.history.pushState({url:'page2.php'}, '', 'page2.php');
  $('body').html('<div class="loading.gif"></div>');

  //Load Page
  $.get('page2.php', function(data){
    $('body').html(data);
  };

  //Edited 
  $(window).bind('popstate', function(event){
    var url = null;

    if (event.state && event.state.url) {
        url = event.state.url;
    } else {
        url = 'index.html'; // or whatever your initial url was
    }

    // Update the contents of the page with whatever url was stored in the state.
    $.get(url, function(data){
        $('body').html(data);
    };
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm pretty novice in JS, could you please tell me how do I implement the popstate event in this case? Thanks!

Comment: I've edited my post, but I'm not sure what to add in the edited section to get the previous content?

Comment: This will not work if clicked multiple pages right? because the initial url has to been updated as well?

Comment: As long as you are pushing the state with enough information to build the previous page contents, it should work fine.